# How to copy multiple files located in several different folders using cmd on Windows?

Tags: file, cmd, directory, copy

I need to copy some .pdf files located in several different folders to one folder I've created. Do you know how to do this using cmd on Windows? I have a .txt file with the names of all those .pdf files I need.

Below are commands that actually work if all the files are located in the same folder, but I don't know how to copy them from several different folders.

```
@echo off
pushd D:\Files
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('type FileList.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy ".\SourceFolder\%a" ".\DestinationFolder"
popd
pause
```

Comment: Have you opened a Command Prompt window, _(`cmd.exe`)_, typed `for /?`, pressed the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information for the `for` command; then typed `xcopy /?`, pressed the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information for the `xcopy` command? This site isn't here to tell you how to do things which may be explained already in the usage information of your used commands, so please tell us which options you've used instead after learning from the output above.

Comment: Also your task has been asked before, what information did you learn from using the search facility at the top of the site pages? This site isn't here to save you from using its search facility, finding code from similar questions and adapting them to your specific needs. We expect from you a [mcve] of the code you've written yourself to perform the task you require of it, but which fails to do so. All you've done is post some code which is not designed to perform the task you require of it, and expecting us to change it accordingly. Please take the [tour], and read through the pages of [ask].